# Importing binary LabVIEW files with header information into MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, binary, bigdata, fread, labview

I have large .bin files (10GB 60GB) that I want to import to MATLAB; each binary file represents the output of two sensors, thus there are too columns of data. Here is [a more manageable sized example of my data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rzut4zbrert9fm0/q9SiZYmrdG).

You will notice that there is a .txt version of the data; I need to upload the .bin files directly to MATLAB, I can't use the .txt version because it takes hours to convert with larger files.

The problem I have is that the .bin file has header information that I can't seem to interpret properly, and thus I cannot extract the data in MATLAB every time I try I seem to get gibberish values.

This is all the information I have about the binary header:

- [Loading Labview Binary Data into Matlab](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Loading-Labview-Binary-Data-into-Matlab/td-p/1107587)
- [LabVIEW Data Logger: Binary Header File Format](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/3efedde4322fef19862567740067f3cc/747b83b6c8e4a6218625669100563b61?OpenDocument)

Any help/advice would be much appreciated I have been trying to solve this problem for days now.

P.S. Someone has already written a function to solve this problem but it does not seem to work with my binary data (could be something to do with the dimensions/size of my data): http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27195-load-labview-binary-data

Below is the code that I am using to import my data, I believe that that d1 and d2 are the dimensions of my binary data. D2 is probably incorrect for the example file in the dropbox because it has been truncated.
The problem I have is that the code extracts my data and I know it is correct because I can check it with the .txt file (also in the drop box) however there are seaming random bad values between the good data points.  These bad values result from the following strings following strings: "NI_ChannelName", "Sensor A", "Sensor B", "NI_UnitDescription", and "Volts" scatted throughout the binary file.

```
clear all
clc
fname = 'RTL5_57.bin';
fid = fopen(fname,'r','ieee-be');
d1 = fread(fid,4);
trash=fread(fid,2,'double');
d2 = fread(fid,4);
trash=fread(fid,1,'double');
data=fread(fid,'double');
```

Comment: you can use `imrotdata`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html, with the property "headerlinesIn"

Comment: do you want to load the whole data-set in once? Or read parts of the data?

Comment: I want to read in the whole data set, I am using a High performance cluster so memory isn’t an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you will need to change the data-format. See [Matlab help](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/fread.html).

Answer (score 0):

https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-39038

Scope:

1) Write a binary file in matlab and read into labview. 2) Write a binary file in labview and read into matlab.

Background:

IMPORTANT:

You must know (3) things about the binary data in the file before you can read the data:

1) what binary format (precision) was used to store the data

2) the exact number of values in the file to read.

3) Endianness
There is no row or column in binary files. Think of a long row/or a long column that needs to be mapped to a 2D array.

Resources on data in binary format.

http://cse.unl.edu/~sincovec/Matlab/Lesson%2024/Binary/CS211%20Lesson%2024%20-%20Binary%20File%20Input-Output.htm