# Read LabView binary of a 1D array of Waveform into MATLAB

Tags: matlab, binaryfiles, labview

I have a VI that uses the Write Waveforms to File (1D) vi to give me a binary file with my n channels of data (waveform of double). I couldn't find any settings in LabView about endian-ness or anything, though I think it's BE by default. I'd like to read this into MATLAB. I've been working on this for a day and haven't made much headway. Does anyone have any information about the header content of a default bin file or some suggestions of how to read the data?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer right away, just a few considerations.

**Write Waveforms to File (1D)** is essentially saving into a [Datalog](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/glang/datalog/) file (just open the block diagram and you'll see).

So you question is more general and about data format of **Datalog** files.

National Instruments  [is warning us](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361D-01/lvconcepts/choosing_a_file_i_o_format/) to "use datalog files to access and manipulate data **only in LabVIEW**"

In fact I could not find a clear format specification on **Datalog** file format, but only [someone else asking](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/What-is-the-format-of-Datalog-files/td-p/737257).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of changing the LabVIEW code, a TDMS file would be the better format to use for this data. This is [documented](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3727/en/) and there is [example code](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7446/en/) for reading it in MATLAB.

If you can't change the format in which the data is written, have you tried the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281788/reading-labview-binary-files-in-matlab?rq=1) or [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318855/importing-binary-labview-files-with-header-information-into-matlab)?